# How to use CSS float without hiding parts of a DIV

Tags: html, css, layout, positioning, css-float

When CSS float is used on a DIV, other DIVs that are not floated continue to occupy the space of the floated DIV.  While I am sure this is intentional, I do not know how to achieve the effect I am looking for.  Please consider this example:

```
<html>

<div style="width:400px">

<div style="width:150px;float:right;border:thin black solid">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.</div>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. 

<div style="background-color:red;border:thin black solid">Some sample text</div>

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
</div>

</html>
```

If you paste this HTML in a browser (or examine its [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MS5z5/)), you'll notice that "Some sample text" is red, and that the red background extends all the way through the floated DIV.  While I am sure there is a way to obscure the parts of the red background I don't want, it would still leave the border cropped off and hidden underneath the DIV.  Ideally, I want the background color and border to only occupy valid text space, and not creep underneath the floated DIV.  Is this effect possible?

Please note that I am using the float property not as a replacement for columns, but as a block that will have the text flow around it.  So far none of the proposed solutions takes this into account.  For clarity, here are some images.

This is what I get:

[image: Bad]

This is what I want:

[image: Good]

You'll notice that in both examples, the final text wraps around the floated part as the text reaches the bottom.  My second example I can achieve by directly specifying the width of the div containing "Some sample text".  I do not want to specify the width.  It seems redundant since I want the same width as that of the text around it.   But perhaps that isn't possible?

Comment: I want to award a bounty to the answer that explicitely states that it's impossible, because this answer (which closes the debate) doesn't have enough attention, and the response with the maximum votes... doesn't answer the question... although it provides valuable information

Comment: @SamuelRossille: I'm not sure what I am missing here (the images above no longer show what was desired). I posted some fiddle links under the accepted answer (at present Kirk Woll's answer) that would seem to indicate cletus's answer was correct (the text still wraps under the right float). Perhaps there was different behavior in older browsers (this thread is over three years old).

Comment: @ScottS, yeah, sorry.  That was back in the bad'ol days where SO didn't have its own internal image hosting solution.  I looked to see if I could recover those images, but to no avail.

Comment: @KirkWoll: That's understandable. Could you possibly comment on my comments under your answer? I don't know what you were trying to achieve (hopefully you remember from that far back), but it would seem that cletus's answer was in fact what you sought (at least as modern browsers interpret it). But I could be missing something here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add a `span` in your `div` and style that like so (of course, I would not actually normally use inline styling):

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
  <span style="background-color:red;
               border:thin black solid;
               display: inline-block;">
   Some sample text
   </span>
</div>
```

Then you can get [this effect shown in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aB9Gg/5/). Note that the `overflow:hidden` on the `div` itself is to accommodate line wrapping for long text strings.

Comment: This was the actual answer I was looking for when asking the question.  Nice job.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to give you what you sought (even if over two years later).

Comment: Better late than never! :)

Comment: @KirkWoll Keep in mind that if the text becomes long enough to require wrapping it will break the layout as it will be moved below the right box http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/MS5z5/2/

Comment: @KirkWoll a solution would be to use `:before` and `:after` to create new-lines but still you cannot style the border correctly for multilines.. http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/MS5z5/4/

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: Actually, just adding `overflow: hidden` to the wrapper `div` solves the line wrapping problem. I've updated my fiddle link in the answer above to [this revised solution](http://jsfiddle.net/aB9Gg/5/), and shown the code change.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one solution:

```
<div style="background-color:red;border:thin black solid;overflow:hidden;">Some sample text</div>
```

Basically the magic here is `overflow: hidden`, which changes the CSS visual formatting model. Take a look at [CSS layout fundamentals, part 5: floats](http://www.mattryall.net/blog/2008/09/css-layout-fundamentals-floats):

> ### Fixing adjacent boxes
>
> Let’s look at the red paragraph border
>   problem first. The reason the
>   paragraph border appears behind the
>   image is because floats don’t
>   reposition block boxes that are
>   adjacent to them. In this example, the
>   floated image is only pushing the line
>   boxes inside the paragraph across. So
>   the text is pushed to the right, but
>   the actual paragraph box still
>   stretches across the full width of the
>   container.
>
> The fix for this issue comes from a
>   very well-hidden paragraph in the
>   [floats section](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats) of the CSS 2.1
>   specification:
>
> > The border box of a table, a
> >     block-level replaced element, or an
> >     element in the normal flow that
> >     establishes a new [block formatting
> >     context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) (such as an element with
> >     ‘overflow’ other than ‘visible’) must
> >     not overlap any floats in the same
> >     block formatting context as the
> >     element itself.
>
> So to prevent our paragraph block from
>   overlapping the floated content, the
>   solution is to create a “new block
>   formatting context”, in CSS
>   specification author terminology.
>   Sounds tricky, eh? Fortunately, it
>   isn’t that hard. New block formatting
>   contexts are created by any block
>   which meets these criteria:
>
> - is floated
> - is absolutely positioned
> - has a display property value of one of more unusual flavours
>     (inline-block, table-cell, etc.)
> - has its overflow property set to something other than visible.
>
> The last option is the one that is
>   easiest to do in most cases: setting
>   overflow: auto on our paragraph will
>   create a new “block formatting
>   context”, and render the paragraph
>   border in the right place.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not allow the text in the "left" column to wrap into the space on the right when the floating div is finished.

Comment: Nothing allows that. You can wrap text around the right float but that will extend the block element to the right as well. A block element is, by definition, a square and you seem to want a square with the top right cut out and the border to follow that line. Can't do it.

Comment: This is what I feared, but thanks for being explicit about it. :)

Answer (score 4):

It appears this is simply not possible the way I had hoped.  As Cletus explained, "Nothing allows that. You can wrap text around the right float but that will extend the block element to the right as well. A block element is, by definition, a square and you seem to want a square with the top right cut out and the border to follow that line. Can't do it."

(I upvoted Cletus' answer, but didn't want to mark it as the correct "answer" because I believe future Googlers should be let down quickly.)

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but the answer from @Cletus seems to work as you desire in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aB9Gg/1/) and [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/aB9Gg/2/).

Comment: @ScottS, hmm, the fiddle in your second comment is exactly what I always longed for.  If you post it as an answer I would love to mark it as the correct answer.  (in fact, *so* pleased, I would love to award it a bounty as well -- isn't this exactly what we're looking for,  Samuel?)

Comment: Added an answer based off my fiddle in the second comment.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the other column as float left. The way that you have it right now the text on the left is going to wrap the floated text on the right. It would also be wise to specify the size of the floated object on the left too.

```
<html>

<div style="width:400px">

<div style="width:150px;float:right;border:thin black solid">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim  veniam.</div>

     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. 

<div style="background-color:red; width: 250px; border:thin black solid">Some sample text

     Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
</div></div>

</html>
```

Also, consider using CSS it will make this code much easier to maintain long-term<<

**EDIT:** I thought you wanted everything to be floated to the left I think I misunderstood your question. What you are trying to do is not possible. The best thing you could do is either specify the margin of the object floated to the right to be equal to 400-150 (250px), or specify the width of the "some text" object to be equal to (250px).

Comment: Thank you, but this does not allow the text in the "left" column to wrap into the space on the right when the floating div is finished.

Comment: Also, using styleshets would strike me as unhelpful inside a question on stack overflow. :)

Comment: OK, I appreciate the response.  For an example of why this is unfortunate, check out this wikipedia article:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata-based_programming.  You'll notice the "Traditional (imperative) program" example is surrounded by a pleasing box much like I've tried to describe here.  Sadly, they ran into the exact same problem and you'll notice the right edge of the box is completely missing because it's obscured underneath the helpful floating navigation div on the right.  Sometimes HTML/CSS makes Jesus cry.

Comment: Hahah, I am sorry I couldn't be of more help. As with any programming language there always are limitations. If there weren't we would use one programming language to do everything. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is only one thing you need to do:

- Give the "sample text" div a right margin, greater than the width of the right-floated element

That should do it.

**Edit:** Based on your edit I would suggest you use a span (an inline element) instead of a div (a block element). If you always need it to be on a separate line, you can give both that element and the element after it a clear:left.

Comment: This would probably work, but it would mean every time I want a little red info box, I have to specify the width explicitly.  That sounds very painful.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately you cannot make the width stretch to the boundaries of the surrounding text.  i.e.  The border and background color will only surround the text you type ( stopping at the end of "text" in "Some sample text") but not fill all the way to to the right edge (where the beginning of the floating div appears).

Answer (score 0):

I came to know this question so late, anyway I am fixing your problem. See this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MS5z5/1/)**

You need to define `display: table;`

As this:

```
<div style="background-color:red;border:thin black solid;display: table;">Some sample text</div>
```

**Note** `display: block;` won't work as `display: table;` and you could also use `display: table-cell;`

You may also like this question: [css inline-block vs table-cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939896/css-inline-block-vs-table-cell)

Comment: just for reference - if you read the Bounty message: the author created it to reward the accepted answer, *rather than* still being looking for an answer.

Comment: @Jesse- Yeah! I know that so I have said came to know late. But answer would help for future readers that's why I have answered.