# css inline-block vs table-cell

Tags: html, css

What are the differences between inline-block and table-cell?

I have found these two styles are the same. Whatever you style for eg. `text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;` etc. by identifying `display: inline-block;` or `display: table-cell;` would work the same.

Please notify the key differences.

Answer (score 22):

`display: table-cell` and `display: inline-block;` are confusing the same but it has huge difference between them. `display: inline-block;` will not behave as the `display: table-cell;` i.e. inline-block will behave as the block level when your browser will be re-sized larger or if your contents exceeds than its width while `display: table-cell;` won't.

You can see the differences between them **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/g5bE8/)**

You'll also find the gap between block when you apply `display: inline-block;` Re-size your window by pressing Ctrl key and scrolling with mouse scroll button to see differences.

Notice the `vertical-align: middle;` is not working as `display: table-cell;` in `display: inline-block;`. If you have working demo please share one.

Comment: Set line-height equal to element height and vertical-align will work for inline-block.

Answer (score 19):

`display:table-cell` is intended for use inside a `display:table-row`, itself inside a `display:table`. Improper use will result in anonymous elements being created, which may interefere negatively with other aspects of your layout.

That being said, `vertical-align` has very different meanings in both. In `display:inline-block`, it refers to how the element itself aligns with the surrounding elements. On the other hand, with `display:table-cell`, it will affect the vertical alignment of elements inside it.