# Clearfix pushing the contents down

Tags: html, css, css-float, clearfix

I've got an Ordered list and the elements inside the `li` item are floating, so I applied the clearfix code to the li, but for some reason the contents on the `li` item is being pushed down.

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/48psdoeu/2/

```css
.true-false ol {} .true-false ol > li:before,
.true-false ol > li:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.true-false ol > li:after {
  clear: both;
}
.true-false ol .question {
  width: 70%;
  padding-top: 0;
  float: left;
}
.true-false ol .answer {
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
}
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="true-false">
  <ol type="i">
    <li>
      <div class="question">
        <p>Always add water to chemicals as fast as possible.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="answer">test</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="question">
        <p>Always keep chemicals in their original container.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="answer">test</div>
    </li>

  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `display: table` declaration messes with the baseline of the text in each `li` element, resulting in the text being pushed down.

`display: table` isn't really needed in a clearfix. In fact, it doesn't actually contribute to making the clearfix work at all. [It's there for a different reason.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699262/css-using-displaytable-with-before-pseudo-element/25701312#25701312) You can replace it with `display: block` instead, and it'll work.

But you really don't need a clearfix here at all. You can just clear the floats normally by applying clearance to each (successive) `li`. The only place I can imagine you'd really need a clearfix is on `.true-false` or `.true-false ol`, but that depends on your layout. What I am certain though is that you absolutely don't need it on the `li` elements.

```css
.true-false ol > li {
  clear: both;
}
.true-false ol .question {
  width: 70%;
  padding-top: 0;
  float: left;
}
.true-false ol .answer {
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
}
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="true-false">
  <ol type="i">
    <li>
      <div class="question">
        <p>Always add water to chemicals as fast as possible.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="answer">test</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="question">
        <p>Always keep chemicals in their original container.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="answer">test</div>
    </li>

  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: It works in FF, but it looks like Chrome still has some rendering issues http://i.stack.imgur.com/MXpCl.png

Comment: @Josh Crozier: Oh god why