# How To Add Bottom Border When Overflow Is Hidden?

Tags: html, css, overflow, border, hidden

**How To Add Bottom Border When Overflow Is Hidden?**

I'm using the [`margin-bottom: -10000px; padding-bottom: 10000px;` trick/hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114757/css-equal-height-columns) to have divs fill their parent container while keeping everything % based. The only problem, the overflow hides the bottom border.

**jsFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/CSS_Apprentice/0Lkxw1je/1/

I'm trying to use `:after` to add the bottom border, but no matter what I do to the :after selector (`position: absolute, overflow: visible`), I can't get the border to show

```
body {
    width: 100%
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 2%;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-bottom: -10000px;
    padding-bottom: 10000px;
}

.box:after {
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    content: '';
}
```

Comment: Try display: table-cell; in .box class instead of  margin-bottom: -10000px; padding-bottom: 10000px;

Comment: It worked, but according to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939896/css-inline-block-vs-table-cell "display:table-cell is intended for use inside a display:table-row, itself inside a display:table. Improper use will result in anonymous elements being created, which may interefere negatively with other aspects of your layout."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This updated css, with  display: table; & display:table-row:-

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;

}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table-row;

}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 2%;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
}

.box:after {
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    content: '';
}

.remainder {
    height: 100%;
}

h1 {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
/* Colors */
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
.green{
    background-color: green;
}
.yellow{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.red{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to create an outer div with a border and without `overflow:hidden`. The outer box will have the border and the content of the inner will be overflow.